# ASP:DropDown Post Back

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I Have a and ASP.NET GridView which is set so

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="Pric_PricingID" 
            DataSourceID="CRMDataSource1" 
            EnableModelValidation="True" 
            GridLines="None" 
            AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" 
            Width="100%" 
            CssClass="GRIDHEAD" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

One of the fields I need to be a drop down value when the row is edited the user will select a value and click update this will then set the column value of price_c_alfsupreq to the select value I believe that this is done using a post back? I am new to this so any help would be fantastic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add a commandfield in your gridview. This will set a "Edit"-button. When this button is clicked, you will get the EditItemTemplates which you see below.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Edit"
        UpdateText="Save">
    </asp:CommandField>
```

And then add a templatefield with a editTemplate inside - here the dropdownlist is enabled, so you can chose from it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dropdown">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Dropdownlist ID="ddl1" runat="server" 
                Enabled="false" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Dropdownlist ID="ddl1Edit" runat="server"
                Enabled="true" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and in your datasource add a UpdateCommand, which evaluates the value in the ddl1Edit.